# does result of pivot need to be a non shared temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I use PIVOT to output a table with an open ended number of columns. In the future, users might need foot_width, the code shouldn't need to be rewritten.

```
DECLARE @COMMA_SEPARATED_KEYS varchar(MAX);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS KV;
CREATE TABLE KV (id_person int, mykey varchar(30), myvalue int);
INSERT INTO KV VALUES
(1, 'age', 16),
(1, 'weight', 63),
(1, 'height', 175),
(2, 'age', 26),
(2, 'weight', 83),
(2, 'height', 185);
WITH cte(mykey) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT mykey FROM KV
) 
SELECT @COMMA_SEPARATED_KEYS=STRING_AGG(mykey,',') FROM cte;
SELECT @COMMA_SEPARATED_KEYS AS keys;
```

[image]

```
DECLARE @ExecuteExpression varchar(MAX);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Pivoted;

SET @ExecuteExpression = N'
SELECT * 
INTO Pivoted
FROM
(
    SELECT
        mykey,
        myvalue,
        id_person
    FROM KV
) AS t
PIVOT(
    MAX(t.myvalue) 
    FOR mykey IN (COMMA_SEPARATED_KEYS)
) AS pivot_table;
';

SET @ExecuteExpression = REPLACE(@ExecuteExpression, 'COMMA_SEPARATED_KEYS', @COMMA_SEPARATED_KEYS);

EXEC(@ExecuteExpression);

SELECT * FROM Pivoted;
```

[image]

This code fails on Msg 2018 Level 16 if Pivoted is turned into a non shared temp table. My spec is that the stored procedure this code will be in could be run by two users in parallel without stepping on each other's toes. What is the easiest solution in 2019 ? If I start the procedure by emptying Pivot ? Could a LOCK be a good solution ?

Comment: What do you mean *"if Pivoted is turned into a non shared temp table"*?

Comment: You can return the data directly, any reason to insert to a table and then select from it?

Comment: @Larnu: if Pivoted is replaced by #Pivoted.

Comment: It's because you're defining `#Pivoted` in the Dynamic SQL connection, and then trying to reference it outside of that connection, @LudovicAubert . A Temporary table only persists for the duration of the connection is was created in. As that connection closes at the end of the dynamic statement, the table `#Pivoted` is dropped. you'd need to define `#Pivoted` outside of the dynamic statement.

Comment: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a051080ee7a006eaef0a4a9697de989b) demonstrating above described behaviour.

Comment: Since the schema is dynamic, what is the best approach today ?

Comment: If all references to the temp table are made from inside the dynamic query, problem is gone. But do all connections share the same Dynamic SQL connection @Larnu ?

Comment: If all the reference are in the **same** dynamic statement, then yes, @LudovicAubert. If you have 2(+) dynamic statements, no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203328/discussion-between-ludovic-aubert-and-larnu).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to put the result into a temp table for further processing, you need to create it ahead of time. The following is the pseudo-code:

```
CREATE TABLE #pivot_results (
  id int identity not null PRIMARY KEY
);
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)=N'';
WITH cte(column_name) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT mykey + ' nvarchar(255) collate database_default null' FROM KV
) 
SELECT @SQL='ALTER TABLE #pivot_results ADD ' + STRING_AGG(column_name, ',') FROM cte;
EXECUTE (@SQL);
```